# Is a literary convention being used in Daniel 12:4?

Tags: daniel, literary-device

I have thought of this for a while and was wondering what literary convention does the following reflect, and why was it used?

> Daniel 12:4 - "But you, Daniel, keep the words secret and the book sealed until the time of the end".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Synonymous Parallelism“ is used in Daniel 12:4.
Secrets are concealed, so the phrase in [12:4] “close up the words and seal the book” ( סְתֹ֧ם הַדְּבָרִ֛ים וַֽחֲתֹ֥ם הַסֵּ֖פֶר ) - states the same idea 2 different ways.

- Refer to https://www.britannica.com/topic/synonymous-parallelism.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just a bit unsure as to why the author chose to use this literary convention in this context. Is there a particular reason other than to amplify and emphasize the following?

Comment: Like Yechezkel (Ezekiel), Daniel was a prophet who associated this poetic style of speaking with the Word of YHVH. * In [Ezekiel 3:3] “Feed your stomach and fill your bowels with this scroll”.